# Try to use “simulatesccsdata” function in SCCS package in R to generate data. But the code is not working

Tags: r, sample

The name of the package is SCCS, and what I am trying to do is just copy the example code in the documents to generate sample data. The codes in the package document as follows:

'''library(SCCS)

set.seed(1234)

arisk = round(runif(110,366,730))

simdata = simulatesccsdata(nindivs = 110,astart = 366,aend = 730,adrug = arisk , aedrug = arisk+20,eexpo = 2.5)

simdata'''

This code is to generate samples, thus should return the data frame. However, for some reason, I only get "1 0"

So, I was wondering if other people also can't run this code even though in a textbook they show the generated data frame from this code.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit late but I rerun your code and I do get the simulated dataframe as expected so I don't get the issue only based on this bit of code

This is what I get based on the code you provided

```
structure(list(indiv = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), astart = c(366, 366, 
366, 366, 366, 366), adrug1 = c(407, 593, 588, 593, 679, 599), 
    aedrug1 = c(427, 613, 608, 613, 699, 619), aend = c(730, 
    730, 730, 730, 730, 730), aevent = c(553, 725, 419, 605, 
    603, 527)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

If it still relevant today i'd try to rerun it in a new script